# Dart pub trigger transformer build

Tags: sass, dart, dart-pub

I'm using Sass in my dart project and build the scss files to css using a transformer. The scss files can import other files so when a scss file is changed all scss files that import the changed file also have to be updated. Currently I run the `touch` cmd to trigger an update on the other files but this causes issues with text editors thinking the file data has changed. Is there a way to trigger `pub` to rebuild specific files?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there isn't.  You can only build all at once or on demand by `pub serve` but `pub serve` doesn't actually create files. SASS can be started as a service to watch for file changes (instead of using the transformer) maybe this route it's easier to get what you want.